# how to solve DeprecationWarning while use of Imputer of sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

scikit-learn provide handy class to take care of missing value of attribute 
Imputer of sklearn.preprocessing

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
im=Imputer(strategy="median")
```

i expect a result but some kind of warning shows

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:66: DeprecationWarning: Class Imputer is deprecated; Imputer was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. Import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning shows that you should be using [SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer) class instead of the Imputer class. The Imputer class is going to be removed in the upcoming versions of scikit-learn. For examples see [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#univariate-feature-imputation). If you still want to use it. You should use the `.fit` method or the `.fit_transform` method of the `Imputer` class.